# Recent Projects List missing when opening QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

When opening QGIS 3.10 on Windows 10 after a recent fresh install to a new computer  using OSGeo4W I seem to be missing the recent Projects Tab. I have News and Project Templates appearing but no recent projects although ones have been opened and worked on since the new install.

Is there an option to turn this on somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: It's likely because there is no recent projects to show - if you open or save a project, does it show?

Comment: no, Ive been using it for few days now and the Recent projects part never shows up in the opening page. I have to manually drag in a project everytime i open it. I have also updated to Developer version 3.10.27 i think and the issue is still occuring.

Comment: I have the same issue with QGIS 3.10.0-3 on Win 7, even after a clean uninstall.

Comment: I have the same issue with 3.10.1 on Windows 10 with a new Q profile. It must be a limited # of affected users as I keep expecting it to show up in the bug reports. I became spoiled having the recent projects on the startup page.

Comment: I'm voting on reopening this question because I am totally unable to understand why this should relate to the *business of vendors and product teams*. This is NEITHER about licensing, pricing, release dates NOR a bug report or an enhancement request. Same here btw: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394287/qgis-newsfeed-missing-on-welcome-screen I feel very uncomfortable with this undemocratic approach to simply delete such questions without giving the community the opportunity to vote on this!

Comment: @JochenSchwarze this question was not deleted.  It was closed by the vote of a moderator and then re-opened by votes from the community.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems the panel is hidden:

Can you try to drag and drop the border of dialog like in this GIF?

[image]

Answer from Nyall, https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33718#issuecomment-573907204

Comment: Exactly the answer I received on github that worked lol Thanks for reminding me I had also asked the same question here. Hope this can help others find the answer too

Comment: Still an issue in QGIS 3.14.16-Pi after a new install. When first drag and drop the border after install, QGIS remembers setting until next QGIS update.

Comment: yeah! well done

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution, the pane is hidden. Seems like a bit of a UI failing on the designers of the welcome page...

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33718#issuecomment-573907204

[image]