# QGIS Newsfeed missing on welcome screen

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I run QGIS 3.18.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, I miss the newsfeed on the welcome page:

[image]

Newsfeed is activated in the settings:

[image]

I was able to solve the missing *Recent Projects* according to the answer on this issue: [QGIS 3.10 Recent Projects List missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342903/qgis-3-10-recent-projects-list-missing) but I was not able to access the newsfeed the same way. Any hints?

Comment: For sure on-topic. Why else otherwise is this not deleted for the same reason then ????? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342903/qgis-3-10-recent-projects-list-missing

Comment: Questions that relate to the business of vendors and product teams, such as licensing, pricing, release dates, submission of bug reports and enhancement requests, etc, are off-topic here and should be directed instead to the official software support teams.

Comment: And could you please clarify why exactly you think that this is the case here and not here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342903/qgis-3-10-recent-projects-list-missing ? It's simply a question about program settings and does REALLY NOT relate to business of vendors and product teams by means of GISSE ruels!

Comment: @JochenSchwarze this question was deleted before being undeleted 3 seconds later, suggesting a deletion in error.  It was closed by the vote of a moderator and then re-opened by votes from the community.  If you seek clarification of why a particular question was closed then that is better asked in a Q&A at [meta.gis.se] rather than in a comment on the Main site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the QGIS options settings as :

1. Go to the QGIS menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> **>** <kbd>options</kbd> **>** <kbd>Advanced</kbd> tab
2. Promise to be careful
3. In the settings tree, go to <kbd>core</kbd> **>** <kbd>NewsFeed</kbd> **>** <kbd>httpsfeedqgisorg</kbd> **>** <kbd>lastFetchTime</kbd>
4. Edit the value and set it at `0`
5. Restart QGIS.

---

**PyQGIS Bonus**

```py
from qgis.core import QgsSettings

qgis_settings = QgsSettings()
qgis_settings.beginGroup("/core/NewsFeed/httpsfeedqgisorg")
qgis_settings.setValue("lastFetchTime", 0)
```